# Simple Express/Node.js MVC Routing Question

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Have a simple routing question. I have my main index.js router, then a secondary router file, and then a controller. For some reason, it will not route to the file correctly and give a 404 error.

routers/index.js

```
"use strict";

const router = require("express").Router();
const documentRoutes = require("./documentRoutes");

router.use("/docs/*", documentRoutes);
```

routers/documentRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var documentController = require("../controllers/documentController");

router.get('/community_service_log.docx', documentController.community_service_log);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/documentController.js

```
"use strict";

var path = require('path');     
var file = path.join(__dirname, '../views/docs/community_service_log.docx');    


module.exports = {
    community_service_log: (req, res) => {
       res.download(file, function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Error");
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log("Success");
       }    
        });
    }
};
```

Yet in the log it shows **"GET /docs/community_service_log.docx 404"**.

I also tried changing

`router.get('/community_service_log.docx', documentController.community_service_log);`

to

`router.get('/docs/community_service_log.docx', documentController.community_service_log);`

but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

The path to the file is correct. It is located at /views/docs/ and in my main app.js file, I have already set the views directory by doing `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the route of `routes/index.js` file from `/docs/*` to `/docs` like this:

```js
router.use('/docs', documentRoutes);
```

Then, access the route using the URL: `http://localhost:3000/docs/community_service_log.docx`

The logs of web server:

```js
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:3000
Success
```

The browser will download the file:

[image]